# Yii2: Model 'fields' ignore null values

Tags: php, yii2

Yii 2 Docs explains that I can set the fields that should be returned by default by `toArray()`.
(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#fields()-detail)

Theres any possibility to ignore when contains null values?

```
function fields() {
    return [
        'email', // Ignore if email is null.
        'fullName', // Ignore if fullName is null.
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function field() {
    $return = [];
    if(!empty($this->email)) {
        $return[] = 'email';
    }
    if(!empty($this->fullName)) {
        $return[] = 'fullName';
    }
    return $return;
}
```